# How to filter by message type before sending a JMS message or send to a particular server?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

Assume Active MQ is the broker and there are 6 servers where JMS listeners are attached.

When a Topic is send then all the six servers will consume the messages.

Now i want a particular server only consume the message instead of all six using selector and it should be filtered before sending the JMS.

How to define a selector in JMS so that the topic will be consumed by a particular server instead of all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need JMS [message selectors](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncer/index.html). There is no need to filter before sending, but upon receiving. An example where only server with id "serv_5" receives the message:

Producer:

```
...
Message message = session.createMessage();
message.setObjectProperty("server_id", "serv_5");
producer.send(message);
```

Consumer (MDB):

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName="jms/YourQueue", activationConfig =  {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode",
                                  propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType",
                                  propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(
                                  propertyName="messageSelector",
                                  propertyValue="server_id = 'serv_5'")

    })
public class YourMessageBean implements MessageListener { ..
```